# Override menu name shown by Superfish in mobile view mode?

Tags: navigation, routes

I've installed [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) and set a new menu. All works fine but when I dive into mobile-view I see the **machine-name** of my menu printed on a rectangle. This could be nice sometimes but I really want to override it to something else rather than *"Main Menu"*.

How will you change that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this in superfish settings. If you have accordion menu it can be set under "Accordion Menu title".

[image]

If you have select menu, there is also an option to change that at "Select settings".

Comment: to be more precise, these setting can be found at the "Superfish plugins" section of settings at "sf-Smallscreen"